# Python classifier, sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification, bayesian

I'm making a classifier
There are 50+ classes, they have 100 + arrays of 100+ elements

More detailed:
There is a dataset of arrays with previously known classes to which they belong

```
dataset = {
"Class 1": [[16, 18, 11, 18], [14, 11, 14, 16], [13, 10, 11, 17]],
"Class 2": [[38, 38, 34, 37], [30, 38, 39, 34], [30, 32, 38, 38]],
"Class 3": [[57, 50, 51, 51], [58, 50, 50, 56], [50, 58, 56, 58]]
}
```

We feed 1 array to the input

```
input_data = [[21, 11, 25, 16]]
```

At the output, I want to get the percentage of the match of my input array with each class

```
Input_data matches:
with Class 1 on - 85%
with Class 2 on - 50%
with class 3 on - 10%
```

There is a condition arrays from the dataset are similar to each other, for example i[0][0] + - similar to i[1][0] and to i[2][0]

The logic as I understand it should be further, I do the standard deviation, but I don't know what's next

```
for key, values in dataset.items():
x1 = values[0][0], values[1][0], values[2][0]
x2 = values[0][1], values[1][1], values[2][1]
x3 = values[0][2], values[1][2], values[2][2]
x4 = values[0][3], values[1][3], values[2][3]

print(np.std(x1, axis=0))
print(np.std(x2, axis=0))
print(np.std(x3, axis=0))
print(np.std(x4, axis=0))
```

I tried the Bayesian classifier, but it doesn't really help

Comment: With your `input_data`, how do you get 10% match with `"Class 3"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes, it is not quite true at the expense of 10%, I put about the numbers, in fact 0% should be

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out
First, I make 1 array with the average values, then we count the average square and divide by N-1.

```
import numpy as np

dataset = {
    "Класс 1": [[16, 18, 11, 18], [14, 11, 14, 16], [13, 10, 11, 17]],
    "Класс 2": [[38, 38, 34, 37], [30, 38, 39, 34], [30, 32, 38, 38]],
    "Класс 3": [[57, 50, 51, 51], [58, 50, 50, 56], [50, 58, 56, 58]]
}

pre_dataset = {"Класс 1": [], "Класс 2": [], "Класс 3": []}

for key, values in dataset.items():
    pre_dataset[key].append(list(np.mean(values, axis=0)))

input_data = [[37, 38, 33, 36]]

res = {"Класс 1": [],
       "Класс 2": [],
       "Класс 3": []}

for i in input_data:
    for k in pre_dataset:
        for row in pre_dataset[k]:
            for a, b in zip(row, i):
                res[k].append(((((a - b) ** 2) / (len(row) - 1)) ** 0.5))

[print(key, sum(values) / len(values)) for key, values in res.items()]
```